# Cast an Expression

Tags: c#, iqueryable, linq-expressions, variance

I have the following:

```
class Base
class Derived : Base
IQueryable<Derived> queryable = ???
Expression<Func<Base, bool>> filter = ???
```

I want to filter the queryable with the expression, and get back an `IQueryable<Derived>`.

However, `Expression` is invariant. That means that `queryable.Where(filter)` gets inferred to be `Where(this IQueryable<Base>, Expression<Func<Base, bool>>)`, and returns `IQueryable<Base>` rather than `IQueryable<Derived>`.

C# doesn't allow for `filter` to be cast to `Expression<Func<Derived, bool>>`, and a cast of the `IQueryable<Base>` returned by `Where` to `IQueryable<Derived>` fails at runtime.

What is the best way around this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The pragmatic fix is:

```
var result = queryable.Where(filter).Cast<Derived>();
```

You could also do it by rewriting the expression tree, but... it doesn't seem worthwhile. But it works:

```
var typed = Expression.Lambda<Func<Derived, bool>>(
        filter.Body, filter.Parameters);
var result = queryable.Where(typed); // IQueryable<Derived>
```

Comment: What's the runtime complexity of `Cast` (or the runtime complexity when the query is executed/result is forced)? It seems wasteful

Comment: @Martijn feel free to measure it... I don't know; it would depend hugely on the `IQuerable<T>` implementation, I guess

Comment: The oneliner `private Expression<Func<A, B>> Upcast<A, B, C, D>(Expression<Func<C, D>> src) where A : C where D : B => Expression.Lambda<Func<A, B>>(src.Body, src.Parameters);`also seems to work like a charm. Thanks for the wonderful lemonade making.

Comment: @Martijn yeah, that should be fine as long as you're talking about classes and/or interfaces; if you add structs, it gets more complex and you'd probably need to inject casts into the tree body, which ... is probably more work than you want to do; might be worth add a `:class` constraint to a few of those types, but... meh, it probably won't matter

Comment: I'll try to experiment with that. I'd much rather have extra casts that are sound than a possibly unsound coercion method. A method that has a signature that promises me something, but throws exceptions at runtime is IMO the worst thing I can possibly have.